# Java 8 Streams - Remove item from nested list based on other list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I remove elements from a `List<String>` property of every object in a collection and return the same collection?

```
class Student { 
    String name; 
    List<String> friends; 

    // TODO constructor, getters and setters
} 

Student chris = new Student("chris", 
    new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("sean", "mike", "mary", "mark"))); 

Student tim = new Student("tim", 
    new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("mike", "john", "steve", "mary"))); 

List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(chris, tim)); 

List<String> badKids = new ArrayList("mike", "sean");
```

I want to return `students` with `friends` list without the `badKids` using streams. Is this possible? The return object would be (using JSON for clarity):

```
[
  { name: "chris", friends: ["mary", "mark"] },
  { name: "tim", friends: ["john", "steve", "mary"]
]
```

I've used streams on collections at a beginner level, but the nesting is what confuses me:

```
List<Student> studentsWithGoodFriends = students.stream()
    .map(student -> student.getFriends().flatMap(student -> student.stream())
    .filter(friend-> !badKids.contains(friend))
    .map(Student student -> new Student...
```

Then I'm lost. I am familiar with returning a list filtered by an object property, but not filtering the list property.

Comment: And what you have tried so far?

Comment: Note that `Arrays.asList()` creates an immutable list. If you create a regular `ArrayList`, you can just do `list.removeAll(otherList);`. There's no need for streams here, but there is a need for correct syntax. At the moment the code is terrible.

Comment: Arrays.asList() doesn't pertain to the problem at hand, changed the code to use ArrayList.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need streams for this task, especially if you want to mutate the list of friends in-place:

```
students.forEach(s -> s.getFriends().removeAll(badKids));
```

And that's it. This uses the [`Collection.removeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) method.

Important: for this to work, the list of friends returned by the `Student.getFriends()` method must be mutable, such as `ArrayList`.

---

Despite the conciseness of the above solution, it breaks encapsulation, because we are mutating the list of friends of every student from outside the `Student` class. To fix this, you'd need to add a method to the `Student` class:

```
void removeBadKids(List<String> badKids) {
    friends.removeAll(badKids);
}
```

Thus, the solution would now become:

```
students.forEach(s -> s.removeBadKids(badKids));
```

Comment: Thank you! I was struggling with the immutability of Arrays.asList() and did not think of this functional example that does not use strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
List<Students> good = st.stream()
        .peek(s -> s.getFriends().removeAll(bad))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But using peek this way (should be used to log) is an anti-pattern, you can use map instead.

```
List<Students> good = st.stream()
        .map(s -> { 
             s.getFriends().removeAll(bad);
             return s;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your code to at least compile first. Stuff like class if a capital C will make your code broken even if your logic works. I tried not to change much, just enough to get it to work, so you can see where you got it wrong.

I also included several examples with different techniques so you can see options involving Streams as you requested, but also, function references and a more traditional one. I hope it helps.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Student {

    String name;
    List< String > friends;

    public Student( String name, List< String > friends ) {

        this.name = name;
        this.friends = friends;
    }

    public void removeFriendsIf( Predicate< String > test ) { // for example 5
        getFriends( ).removeIf( test );
    }

    public List< String > getFriends( ) { // for example 4 -> students.forEach( e -> e.getFriends().removeIf( badKids::contains ) );

        return friends;
    }

    public void removeFriends( List< String > badFriends ) { // no need for example here
        getFriends( ).removeAll( badFriends );
    }
}

class Initech {

    public static void main( String[] reports ) {

        Student chris = new Student( "chris", Arrays.asList( "sean", "mike", "mary", "mark" ) );
        Student tim = new Student( "tim", Arrays.asList( "mike", "john", "steve", "mary" ) );
        Student other = new Student( "tim", Arrays.asList( "john", "steve", "mary" ) );
        List< Student > students = new ArrayList<>( );
        students.add( chris );
        students.add( tim );
        students.add( other );
        List< String > badKids = Arrays.asList( "mike", "sean" );

        // Example 1 ----
        // All students that do not have any of the bad friends
        List< Student > studentsWithOnlyGoodFriends = students.stream( )
                                                              .filter( e -> e.friends.stream( )
                                                                                     .noneMatch( badKids::contains ) )
                                                              .collect( Collectors.toList( ) );

        studentsWithOnlyGoodFriends.stream( )
                                   .map( e -> e.friends )
                                   .forEach( System.out::println );

        System.out.println( );

        // Example 2 ----
        // All students but removing the bad apples
        List< Student > studentsLostBadFriends = students.stream( )
                                                         .peek( e -> e.friends = e.friends.stream( )
                                                                                          .filter( f -> !badKids.contains( f ) )
                                                                                          .collect( Collectors.toList( ) ) )
                                                         .collect( Collectors.toList( ) );

        studentsLostBadFriends.stream( )
                              .map( e -> e.friends )
                              .forEach( System.out::println );

        System.out.println( );

        //Example 3 ----
        // The same as 2, without streams and with ArrayLists

        chris = new Student( "chris", new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( "sean", "mike", "mary", "mark" ) ) );
        tim = new Student( "tim", new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( "mike", "john", "steve", "mary" ) ) );
        other = new Student( "tim", new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( "john", "steve", "mary" ) ) );

        students.add( chris );
        students.add( tim );
        students.add( other );

        students.forEach( e -> e.friends.removeIf( badKids::contains ) );

        students.stream( )
                .map( e -> e.friends )
                .forEach( System.out::println );

        //Example 4 ----
        // The same as 3, without streams and with ArrayLists and the getter methods

        chris = new Student( "chris", new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( "sean", "mike", "mary", "mark" ) ) );
        tim = new Student( "tim", new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( "mike", "john", "steve", "mary" ) ) );
        other = new Student( "tim", new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( "john", "steve", "mary" ) ) );

        students.add( chris );
        students.add( tim );
        students.add( other );

        students.forEach( e -> e.getFriends( )
                                .removeIf( badKids::contains ) );

        students.stream( )
                .map( e -> e.friends )
                .forEach( System.out::println );

        //Example 5 ----
        // The same as 4, without streams and with ArrayLists and the getter methods

        chris = new Student( "chris", new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( "sean", "mike", "mary", "mark" ) ) );
        tim = new Student( "tim", new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( "mike", "john", "steve", "mary" ) ) );
        other = new Student( "tim", new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( "john", "steve", "mary" ) ) );

        students.add( chris );
        students.add( tim );
        students.add( other );

        students.forEach( e -> e.removeFriendsIf( badKids::contains ) );

        students.stream( )
                .map( e -> e.friends )
                .forEach( System.out::println );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for example on this way:

```
package demo;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> students = asList(getChris(), getTim());

        List<String> badFriends = asList("mike", "sean");

        List<Student> cleanedStudentList = students.stream()
                .map(student -> cleanBadFriendOnStudent(student, badFriends))
                .collect(toList());

        cleanedStudentList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static Student cleanBadFriendOnStudent(Student student, List<String> badKids) {
        List<String> cleanedFriendList = student.friends.stream()
                .filter(not(badKids::contains))
                .collect(toList());
        return new Student(student.name, cleanedFriendList);
    }

    private static <T> Predicate<T> not(Predicate<T> predicate) {
        return predicate.negate();
    }

    private static Student getTim() {
        return new Student("tim", asList("mike", "john", "steve", "mary"));
    }

    private static Student getChris() {
        return new Student("chris", asList("sean", "mike", "mary", "mark"));
    }

    private static class Student {
        private final String name;
        private final List<String> friends;

        Student(String name, List<String> friends) {
            this.name = name;
            this.friends = friends;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Student{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", friends=" + friends +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Student{name='chris', friends=[mary, mark]}
Student{name='tim', friends=[john, steve, mary]}
```